# Dynamically showing a control next to other controls, in different containers

Tags: .net, winforms

I have textboxes named SupplierName and ProductName which is on `groupbox1` and a `gridview1` that appears like intellisense.

For example, when I enter "s" in SupplierName, the `gridview1` takes customer names that start with "s" from database and it is dynimically located at the base of the current word in SupplierName textbox like intellisense.

It looks fine with SupplierName textbox but the ProductName textbox is on `groupbox1` 
and I cant locate `gridview1` on `groupbox1` to appear near ProductName textbox.
it only appears near SupplierName textbox even if I'm entering text in ProductName textbox.

Here is the code where `tb` is textbox parameter that take the name of textbox which is currently entered text:

```cs
int i = tb.SelectionStart;
...
Point pt = tb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(i);
pt.Y += (int)Math.Ceiling(tb.Font.GetHeight());
pt.Y += 2;
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(tb.Handle))
{  
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString(tb.Text, tb.Font);
    if (size.Width > tb.Width)
    {
        // float length = size.Width % txtintellisense.Width;
        pt.X += tb.Width;
    }
    else
    pt.X += (int)size.Width;
}
Point point = tb.Location;
pt.X += point.X;
pt.Y += point.Y;
this.dGVinvisible.Location = pt;
this.dGVinvisible.BringToFront();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this ..

```
Point point = tb.Location;
Point point0 = GroupBox1.Location;
pt.X += point.X + point0.X;
pt.Y += point.Y + point0.Y;
this.dGVinvisible.Location = pt;
```

you may set DGV parent to GroupBox1 .. `dGVinvisible.Parent = GroupBox1`

Comment: @deva .. first code would be better if it worked for you. If you choose the second option, you should set your DGV container in every GetFocus event on controls that have different container ..

Comment: @deva .. feel free to vote this as the answer if this help you .. X)

Answer (score 0):

The `Location` of `ProductName` TextBox is relative to the GroupBox, but your code treats it as being relative to the Form. You need to offset the coordinates by adding the GroupBox coordinates to them.

```
pt.Offset(groupBox.Location);
this.dGVinvisible.Location = pt;
```